# Kotlin 1.2.50 and databinding issue

Tags: data-binding, android-databinding, kotlin-android-extensions

Today I just updated my project to use kotlin 1.2.50 and after when I started compilation i just get an errors :

> \app\build\intermediates\feature_data_binding_base_feature_info\demoDebug\dataBindingExportFeaturePackageIdsDemoDebug\out' specified for property 'annotationProcessorOptionProviders$kotlin_gradle_plugin.$0.$0.baseFeatureInfoDir' does not exist.
>
> \app\build\intermediates\feature_data_binding_base_feature_info\demoDebug\dataBindingExportFeaturePackageIdsDemoDebug\out' specified for property 'databinding.baseFeatureInfoDir' does not exist.

On version 1.2.41 compile well.

Does anyone know what is the issue in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today update for Android Studio solve the issue.

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta01' 
-> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta02'

Comment: At which version you have updated your android studio.

Comment: I am also getting the same issue. Getting ClassCastException in binding. is that the same issue you were facing ?